# Separating objects from source

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to splitting some source which is used to change the behavior of my application at runtime. I'll have to parse it and execute it dynamically. I need a way to split the source into a list of `object`. Here's an example script.

I am trying to divide the source into different parts for parsing it.

Here's a single string of source which is entered into a text box in my app.

```
object obj1 {

    event onCreate {
        set name "OBJ1"
        set x 150
    }

}

object obj2 {

    event onCreate {
        set name "OBJ2"
        set x 50
    }

}
```

I need to divide them into two strings such as

string obj1

```
object obj1 {

    event onCreate {
        set name "OBJ1"
        set x 150
    }

}
```

string obj2

```
object obj2 {

    event onCreate {
        set name "OBJ2"
        set x 50
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: "splitting some source " how?

Comment: Can you try expand on your original post?  It's not very clear what you are attempting and what you have already tried.

Comment: @Saurabh The objects should be divided into separate strings.

Comment: How anybody could grasp what the problem is here is beyond me. What specifically are you struggling with?

Comment: So, you can parse and dynamically execute event-handling source code and still don't know how to split text by keyword?

Comment: I need to split it to parse it.

Comment: It appears he is taking input of the Type and the assigned name for some object and wanting to parse it and then set some other values based on it....sounds like usage of a config file would work since its changing the application at runtime

Comment: You need something like regex, with pattern like `object ... { ... }`, unfortunately I don't master that much with regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you suppose that your code is syntactically correct (i.e. it's got the correct number of curly brackets), you can start from something like the following method and improve it. It looks for opening and closing brackets in your code, keeping trace of the opened brackets and separating the string as soon as every opened bracket has been close.

You can't simply use Split, since it would not work as soon as the token you are using (e.g. object) is used not only as a separator.

```
    public List<string> Split(string src)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        int brk = src.IndexOf('{');
        if (brk < 0)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(src.Trim()))
                result.Add(src);
            return result;
        }
        string cur = src.Substring(0, brk + 1);
        string remainder = src.Substring(brk + 1);
        int countBrk = 1;
        while (countBrk > 0)
        {
            int idxOpened = remainder.IndexOf('{');
            int idxClosed = remainder.IndexOf('}');
            if (idxOpened >= 0 && idxOpened < idxClosed)
            {
                countBrk++;
                cur = cur + remainder.Substring(0, idxOpened + 1);
                remainder = remainder.Substring(idxOpened + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                countBrk--;
                cur = cur + remainder.Substring(0, idxClosed + 1);
                remainder = remainder.Substring(idxClosed + 1);
            }
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cur.Trim()))
            result.Add(cur);
        result.AddRange(Split(remainder));
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string strSource = @"Your code";
string objects = string.Split("object", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Use [string.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.string.split.aspx) to get what you want. Split by the keyword `object`. Obviously, this would be reliant on your source code example being correct because should you have any `object` types in your code, it would also split those.

If you google:

> Split string c#

The above is what you would find. Just takes a bit of research.